# How to merge two strips in video editing mode?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I have more than 30 video strips of a process and I want to merge then to apply a speed effect just one time.
The total time is more than 20 hours and I would like to merge the strips and use the effect before render... 20 hours rendering to then start edit isn't a solution, ok?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have "*metastrips*" which work very similarly to node groups:

Select the strips you want to "merge", hit <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to put them in a metastrip.

You can access the metastrip's content by selecting it and pressing <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> to enter inside, and <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> again to get out.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, it help me a lot. My idea about groups was to group verticaly, I would never try to use Ctrl+G.